# Grepping an specific command give me an old grep output

Tags: ssh, putty, grep, pipe

I need some help, wasn't able to find a solution...

I've made a script to run xfs_growfs and pipe its output to know only if the it found no difference is disk size and gave me an "data size unchanged" in it's output...

Then now when I run that command and pipe grep it's output looking for a string that I know it's not in the first command output it always give me that output:

`xfs_growfs -d /mnt/lun1 | grep "Anything that is not in the first command output..."`

`data size unchanged, skipping`

I've tested to see if it was some problem with the xfs_growfs command but if I redirect it's output to null it shows nothing, expected behavior

`xfs_growfs -d /mnt/lun1 > /dev/null 2>&1`

I've tested the grep command... No unnusual behavior:

`cat /etc/fstab | grep "DDD"`
`#`

I've closed putty thinking it could be a variable I've setted,even made a new script with the same command because I don't know what to do anymore... I can't reboot this system right now, that output problem is not causing any big trouble, but it's really a pain in the assets.

Can you guys give me any ideas how to fix this?

UPDATE: one more thing I just found...

If you try another valid device and pipe grep it's output, it also behave the same why. If I try to run it on a device that doesn't exist, it give me the first command error:

`xfs_growfs -d /mnt/lun2 | grep "Anything that is not in the first command output..."`

`data size unchanged, skipping`

`xfs_growfs -d /mnt/lun323 | grep "DOXONO"`

`xfs_growfs: path resolution failed for /mnt/lun323: No such file or directory`

Comment: Compare to [*How do I grep help output in linux?*](https://superuser.com/q/243610/432690) Note when you redirected to `/dev/null`, you also used `2>&1`. If you did not use it, it might give you a clue. It's not clear if you want to grep for `data size unchanged, skipping` or if you want to grep for something else and not see this `data size unchanged, skipping`. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are getting is most probably something that `xfs_growfs` sends to the standard error. The pipe symbol (`|`) normally only pipes the standard output, and the standard error goes still to the terminal, `grep` doesn't even see the `data size unchanged, skipping` line.

In the line you redirect the output, you don't get that line, because there you explicitly redirect also the standard error (the `2>&1` part does that).

If you want in your `xfs_growfs` command to ignore the standard error, you have to do something like this:

```
xfs_growfs -d /mnt/lun1 2>/dev/null | grep "Anything that is not in the first command"
```

This should give you no output at all.

Comment: Yeah... just found it out right now messing around with the outputs... ( >1 and >2 ....), know I understand better that topic... I'm feeling a bit noob now... Well, thank you very much for the fast reply.